# Jhipster project runs fine on Mac, but fails to run on Linux

Tags: maven, ubuntu, jhipster

I have a JHipster project that includes Spring Boot and React Native. I run it OK using ./mvnw as the guide specifies, however, when I put the entire project on Ubuntu, it fails to run and the log is as follows:

```
ERROR Failed to execute goal 
com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.8.0:npm (webpack build dev) 
on project galley-1: Failed to run task: 'npm run webpack:build' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 2 (Exit value: 2) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.8.0:npm (webpack build dev)
```

Some points to note are that: I use sudo, and I already changed the webpack space size to be as big as 9000, in package.json.

Comment: I'm not sure you pasted the most valuable part of the error because here it seems we see only the end of it. Why do you run as sudo?

Comment: Using sudo because I run other scripts like postgres and keycloak all using sudo, so I use sudo to run this as well. thanks for answer~

Comment: You did not answer my request to get full error. About sudo, even for postgresql and keycloak, it is not required and risky. Do run your app on this box for dev or for prod?

Comment: Thanks Gael. I actually solve this issue by another way (I used java -jar ...). But just curious, why using sudo is risky ... I know it may relate to admin rights or something of that sort, but don't know the details (OK, maybe I should google it by myself...) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my own question, I finally find a way to run this:

On mac, I package my project using 'mvn -Pprod package -DskipTests' (sorry there were some tests that didn't pass at that time, I didn't get time to fix those at that time), and then on Linux:
nohup sudo java -jar *.jar &

It will do the trick. But if anyone gets any better idea, please share.